# SQL Server scalar valued function: how to return a boolean following a GroupBy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three connected tables: Cluster, ClusterMember and ClusterKeyword.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cluster] 
(
    [Id]       SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [IntentId] TINYINT  NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] SMALLINT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Cluster] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClusterMember] 
(
    [Id]        SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [ClusterId] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [PageId]    INT      NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ClusterMember] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ClusterMember_Page] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([PageId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PageNode] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ClusterMember_Cluster] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ClusterId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Cluster] ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClusterKeyword] 
(
    [MemberId]  SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [KeywordId] INT      NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ClusterKeyword] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MemberId] ASC, [KeywordId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ClusterKeyword_ClusterMember] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([MemberId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ClusterMember] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ClusterKeyword_Keyword] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([KeywordId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Keyword] ([Id])
);
```

I'm trying to create a **check constraint** function on the `ClusterKeyword` table that ensures the `KeywordId` can only exist once for each `IntentId` - which is set in the `Cluster` table.

So:

```
keyword1 => member1 => cluster1 (intent 1)
keyword1 => member2 => cluster2 (intent 2)
```

*different intents: is okay*

```
keyword1 => member1 => cluster1 (intent 1)
keyword1 => member2 => cluster2 (intent 1)
```

*same intents: is NOT okay*

Here's where I'm at with the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ClusterKeywordMismatches(@KeywordId INT)
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN RETURN (
    SELECT max(COUNT(*))
    FROM Cluster c
    LEFT JOIN ClusterMember cm
    ON cm.ClusterId = c.Id
    LEFT JOIN ClusterKeyword ck
    ON ck.MemberId = cm.Id
    WHERE ck.KeywordId=@KeywordId
    GROUP BY c.IntentId)
END
```

I need it to return a single variable - preferably a boolean - to indicate if the entry can be added.

- If there are multiple rows with the same intent `IntentId`, it should
  fail.
- If there are multiple rows but all have different intents it should
  pass.

Needless to say it doesn't work right now.

Comment: @Stu sorry, you're right, I missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You don't need a `CHECK` constraint.** There are all [manner of issues](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/313310/what-is-the-current-state-2022-of-using-udfs-in-a-check-constraint-in-sql-serv) with using scalar functions in check constraints, compounded by the fact it is doing table access.

You can use an indexed view to enforce this. An indexed view has a unique clustered index on it, which (if you define the index correctly) will ensure there is only ever one row per `KeywordId, IntentId` pair.

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwKeywordByIntent
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

SELECT
  ck.KeywordId,
  c.IntentId,
  OtherColumnsHereIfYouWant
FROM dbo.Cluster c
JOIN dbo.ClusterMember cm ON cm.ClusterId = c.Id
JOIN dbo.ClusterKeyword ck ON ck.MemberId = cm.Id;
```

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX vwKeywordByIntent_UQ ON dbo.vwKeywordByIntent
  (KeywordId, IntentId)
```

Comment: Brilliant, just what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just wrap your query in a `CASE` statement?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ClusterKeywordMismatches(@KeywordId INT)
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN 
RETURN (
    SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN (
                SELECT max(COUNT(*))
                FROM Cluster c
                LEFT JOIN ClusterMember cm ON cm.ClusterId = c.Id
                LEFT JOIN ClusterKeyword ck ON ck.MemberId = cm.Id
                WHERE ck.KeywordId=@KeywordId
                GROUP BY c.IntentId
            ) > 1 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END AS SomeName
)
END
```

Comment: `CASE` is not a statement, and `MAX(COUNT(*))` is not valid nor do I see how it could ever make sense. Also why `LEFT JOIN` when you have a `WHERE` it's effectively an `INNER`